# Conditional Clauses

Tags: conditionals

I wonder if you could tell me the difference(s) between the following questions:

1. If you **could have lived** in another period, which period would you choose?
2. If you **could live** in another period, which period would you choose?

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple, the first example is in Past Tense, while the second is in Present Tense.

> If you could have lived in another period, which period would you choose?

Here, one (person) asks another if he/she **had gotten** a chance to live in another period, the which *would it have been*.

> If you could live in another period, which period would you choose?

Here, one (person) asks another if he/she **gets** a chance to live in another period, which *will it be*.